# Rails dependency problem within CI Joe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration

I am using [cijoe](https://github.com/defunkt/cijoe) to do continuous integration on my rails app. It runs "rake test" after each push to github.

cijoe returns this on my ci server:

```
Could not find factory_girl-1.3.3 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Whereas locally it runs find. Both my integration server and development machine use rvm and ruby 1.9.2

bundle install is properly ran on the ci server after each pull.

In run cijoe in this manner

```
nohup cijoe . &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with CI joe, it is being fixed [here](https://github.com/defunkt/cijoe/pull/54#issuecomment-1190691). The patch worked fine for me.